# Mathematical induction on set of positive integers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

The exercise asks to do the following proof:

Use mathematical induction to show that given a set of $n+1$ positiv eintegers, none exceeding $2n$, there is at least one integer in this set that divides another integer in the set. My idea was the following

BASIS: $n=1$. Let $X$ be a set that includes two single positive integer, so that its cardinality is $n+1$ and such that $n\leq2n$. Then there exists a positive integer that divide another integer in the set (for instance any memebr of the set is divisible by itself).

STEP: Let $T$ be a set of cardinality $n+2$ such that $n+1\leq2n+2$. This means that $T=S\cup\{a\}$ where $S$ and $\{a\}$ are both subset of $T$.

Now $S$ has cardinality $k+1$. By inductive hypothesis, then there is an integer $x$ in $S$ that divides another integer $y$ in $S$. Then, since S is a subset of T, this means that that couple is included in $T$. So in $T$ there is an integer that divides another integer in $T$ and this should complete the proof.

I am not sure I expressed a right reasoning here, so I would like to ask for some help in the resolution.

Comment: Thanks, i will  work with the right understanding of the question

Answer (score 4):

This is not a valid proof. First of all, the proof clearly requires that there be two *distinct* integers, one of which divides the other.

Your proof doesn't seem to display understanding of how the induction is supposed to work.

> Let $X$ be a statement that includes two single positive integer, so that its cardinality is $n + 1$ and such that $n \leq 2n$.

It's irrelevant that $n \leq 2n$. Furthermore, you know exactly what $n$ is in the base case - it's $n = 1$. So the base case should begin with

> Let $X$ be a set of $1 + 1 = 2$ positive integers, each of which is $\leq 2 \cdot 1 = 2$.

From here, you can determine exactly what $X$ is and then prove the base case.

Similarly, the inductive step should begin with

> Suppose that for any set $Y$ of $n + 1$ distinct positive integers, all of which are $\leq 2n$, there are two distinct elements of $Y$ where one divides the other. Suppose $X$ is a set of $(n + 1) + 1 = n + 2$ distinct positive integers, all of which are $\leq 2(n + 1) = 2n + 2$.

You should then perform some case analysis on $X$ to find two distinct elements of $X$ where one divides the other.

Comment: So, how should induction be used to attack the problem?   For example, suppose that there is a set $S$ that contains exactly $n$ elements, where $S \subset \{1,2,\cdots,2n\}.$ Further suppose that there are no distinct elements $s,t$ in $S$ such that $~s ~| ~t.~$  Now consider $S \cup \{2n+1, 2n+2\}.$  How would one prove that one of the elements in $S$ is a divisor of either $(2n+1)$ or $(2n+2)$?

Comment: @user2661923 The key here is to note that $S$ must have some factor of $n + 1$ in it. For if $S$ did not have a factor of $n + 1$ in it, then we could add $n + 1$ to $S$ to get a set with $n + 1$ distinct elements.

Comment: +1 to answer : Nice response to comment.